# Why is TCP port 514 open on my Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: networking

TCP port 514 is open on my system, and I don't know why.

Here's what I see:

[image]

As far as I know, I haven't enabled any rlogin/ssh services. Can somebody help me track down why this port is open, and/or what's using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah... I had enabled port 514 in /etc/rsyslog.conf to allow syslog entries from my router...

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
```